# Reject calls with WhatsApp message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, call-screening

Is there any app or any way to reject a call with a message sent via WhatsApp? Normally when we get a call there is an option to reject it with a pre-written SMS, but I was wondering if you can use WhatsApp to send these template messages.

Comment: IMHO: That's very much up to WhatsApp to support such a feature. If it doesn't, file a feature request for it upstream.

Comment: I think part of the point of blocking someone is not letting them know you've done so. If the blocked number is a bot/machine it would probably won't do much with a block message. either way it's basic enough feature to request it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `WhatsApp` [FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000016), it looks like this feature is currently NOT Supported by `WhatsApp`.

In Summary, When someone calls you, you will see an incoming `WhatsApp` call screen. And you can tap on the message icon on the call screen to decline the call with a quick message.

**But for Above steps to work, the Incoming call HAS TO BE WhatsApp Call and NOT the regular cellular call.**

Hence, currently user needs to use native/in-built app Like SMS/Hangout to Reject call with message.

Answer (score 1):

There is a app for android to cater your need.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.berightback&hl=en

What it does?

1. Install the app and enable accessibility for BRB.
2. Enable service.
3. Once you reject a call, the app helps you to compose a personalised WhatsApp message on your contacts chat window. You just have to tap send.
4. Apart from this, it reminds you to

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted, you can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) to do this. Set up a profile that runs on missed call and triggers a task that runs the shell commands listed here: (http://tasker.wikidot.com/whatsapp-send-message). Just ignore the AutoVoice commands used to get input and hard-code the message you want sent.

Answer (score 0):

I made this app with the exact requirement as yours, I hoope you like it

[Reject Calls With WhatsApp Message](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=swappy.rcwm)

Comment: The link is dead, can you please take a look at it?

Comment: @GokulNC Link updated. The app was stuck in conflict with whats app, Now we are clear. Enjoy the app